# Объединение повторных лидов и сделок с помощью роботов или другими способами с вычислением итоговой суммы

Tags: windows, битрикс24, автоматизация, crm

Есть повторные лиды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и есть на их основании повторные сделки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Как выделить (и объединить) повторные лиды с помощью робота (или с помощью бизнес-процесса)?
2. Как объединить вручную повторные лиды в один лид **с суммой, равной сумме сумм лидов**?
3. Как выделить (и объединить) повторные сделки с помощью робота (или с помощью бизнес-процесса)?
4. Как объединить вручную повторные сделки в одну сделку **с суммой, равной сумме сумм сделок**?

(желательно показать скриншоты этих действий)

Читал [Объединение лидов и сделок](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/10374194/), но там не показано, как задавать в итоговом лиде/сделке **сумму, равную сумме сумм объединяемых лидов/сделок**. Там сказано

> В одном и том же поле в карточках может быть указана разная информация. Выберите нужное значение для итоговой карточки. Для этого просто кликните на него.

Т.е. значение поля в итоговой карточке задается полем одной из объединяемой карточки, а не как сумма полей объединяемых карточек.

По поводу роботов - нажал на кнопку **роботы** и **создать**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куда далее идти для объединения лидов и сделок - не знаю (может быть надо вообще как-то иначе двигаться, не знаю).